# Mule ESB open source for production

Tags: mule, open-source, esb, middleware, mule-cluster

I am new to Mule ESB. We like to use Mule ESB as integration tool for our applications to integrate with vendor site. We have 2 questions.

1) mule ESB is completely open source tool for production and development environment ?

2) We have went through few sites and blogs and found below information. Can you please correct us if our understanding is incorrect.

a) Mule ESB community Edition - Free for production and non production. But could not find the link to download the Mule ESB software. 
    b) Mule ESB enterprise Edition - 30 day free trial version. Then monthly subscription amount will be decided by Mule (silver,Gold,Platinum)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Mule has two versions: Community and Enterprise. [Community version has CPAL license](https://developer.mulesoft.com/licensing-mule-esb) which allows you to run Mule in production, gives you access to the code and make code changes if you need. Enterprise version has a commmercial license, you can find more information [here](https://www.mulesoft.com/).
Here is the link for downloading Mule Community Edition: https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Yes Mule community edition is free for production and non-production and can be downloaded from [here](https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime), the licensing is tricky with Mule and it would be best to read through it completely.

If you are considering with enterprise edition do get in touch with MuleSoft they will be able to help you out.

Also look out for other options like Spring Integration and Apache Camel if you are looking at low cost options ...

Answer (score 0):

Mule has two versions: Community and Enterprise. Community version allows you to run Mule in production, gives you access to the code and make changes in code. Enterprise version has a commmercial license, wecan find more information here. chk this link

https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime